# python: ValueError: Length of values (20) does not match length of index (10) getting error while inserting data to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fetch url from excel sheet then used that url to fetch image and run tessarct ocr and after getting **result from ocr I am inserting ocr result into excel**, while, **2 other values inserting successfully into excel sheet, `df1['image text'] = img_text_list` giving me an error** `ValueError: Length of values (20) does not match length of index (10)` `df1['image text']` contains long string. How Will I insert the value into the excel sheet ?

**When tried to insert value of string length (10) by truncating the value of `df1['image text']` that was inserted successfully** but I need to insert whole resulted text into the excel not truncated values. How will I resolve this error?

data which is inserting into excel

```
|url           |img url             |alt text| image text                             |
|--------------|------------------- |--------|--------------------------------------- |
| abc.com/image|abc.com/image/2.jpg |        | How the Sangh Parivar Business         |
|              |                    |        | Understands the fundamentals.          |
|              |                    |        | Goyal Confederation of Indian Industry |
|              |                    |        | (CII) in a meeting                     |
|              |                    |        | Said that the Tata group new e-        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        | You are welcome. But                   |
|              |                    |        | In the mess...when I name like this    |
|              |                    |        | study with someone else                |
|              |                    |        | in partnership with everyone           |
|              |                    |        | It's obviously Starbucks               |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
| abc.com/image|abc.com/image/3.jpg |        | GST implemented in a hurry, increasing |
|              |                    |        | Tariff barriers and now countries      |
|              |                    |        | amid accusations of being hostileIndus |
|              |                    |        | If the business world                  |
|              |                    |        | confused about relationships-          |
|              |                    |        |  As a human always said                |
|              |                    |        | You are welcome. But                   |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
|              |                    |        |                                        |
```

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pt
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pathlib


img_text_list = []
urls_list = []
img_list = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['url', 'img url', 'image text'])
img_formats = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".webp"]

df = pd.read_csv("urls.csv")
urls = df["urls"].tolist()


for y in urls:
    response = requests.get(y)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    img_tags = soup.find_all('img', class_='pick')

    img_srcs = ["https://abc.in/" + img['src'].replace(
        '\\', '/') if img.has_attr('src') else '-' for img in img_tags]
    img_alts = [img['alt'] if img.has_attr('alt') else '-' for img in img_tags]

    for count, x in enumerate(img_srcs):
        img_list.append(x)
        urls_list.append(y)

        if x != '-':
            print(pathlib.Path(x).suffix)
            if pathlib.Path(x).suffix in img_formats:
                response = requests.get(x)
                print(response)
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
            text = pt.image_to_string(img, lang="hin")
            img_text_list.append(text)
        else:
            img_text_list.append("not supported")
    else:
        img_text_list.append("no src")


df1['url'] = urls_list
df1['img url'] = img_list
df1['image text'] = img_text_list
df1.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute and fix your indentation. Would be great. Thanks

Comment: did you try to print the 3 lists before inserting to the df? Maybe you see at the data itself where your code went wrong.

Comment: yes, there is no issues in printing 3 list , though `df1['image text'] = img_text_list` data seems really really large as compared to other

Comment: it says length is expected to 20 but it is only 10, that isn't really really large and could be checked manually. BTW as long as we don't have any data to run the code ourselves we can't do much here but guessing.

Comment: @HedgeHog apologies for indentation!

Comment: @Rabinzel I have added a dummy data which is coming by data frame and needs to insert in excel

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that for/else statement. Your code is constructed in a way that to each of them 3 lists elements are appended in every single iteration EXCEPT if there is no src. Then instead of x elements (of length of `img_srcs`) you only append once an element to `img_text_list` while you still append multiple arguments to both other lists.

Comment: so what should I do now? any pseudo code

Comment: Wait I just tried that for/else myself to test behaviour. That else statement at the end will always be executed if the for loop gets finished (for/else usually has a break statement somewhere in the if which you don't have). Delete that else statement with "no src" at the end and see if the code runs.

Comment: yes after removing `else statement` with `no src` this works like a chamr! Thank you so so much